# is it possible to add angular or react to existing asp.net core 2.1 application as segregate project in solution?

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

I have asp.net core 2.1 application wondering if I could add angular or react to my application as separate project and run them on one port.

I would like to build a dashboard using angular or react and keep my existing application.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create a folder for your SPA app, for example `ClientApp` and inside that folder create a normal Angular/React app.

Then in your startup.cs inside `Configure` after `UseAuthentication` and `UseMvc`:

```
app.UseSpa(config =>
{
    config.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; // your SPA path

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        config.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200"); // your SPA server
});
```

And now you can request to your .NET app port and if it doesn't match by `UseMvc` it will be forwarded to your SPA.

For publishing you need to tell .NET where to look, for example inside `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"; // your publish path
});
```

[SPA Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)